# Does the ASP.Net Wizard Control work with javascript disabled?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, controls

Isn't this a client side control?

What will happen if the user has disabled javascript?

Comment: I'm sure Microsoft have implemented a server-side equivalence of the client-side code. Have you tried it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.  It is not affected by javascript support.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I *rarely* use this control, but it plays an important role in an app I'm working on and have open on my desktop right now.  So I checked: I disabled javascript for the page with NoScript and it still did exactly what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends if you use button or linkbuttons for the previous / next links. The former doesn't require javascript, the latter will.